# Svelte Custom Stores with Objects: How do I only update one key at a time?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have the following store:
import {writable} from 'svelte/store';

```js
function playerRes(info) {
    const { subscribe, set, update } = writable(info);

    return {
        subscribe,
        add: (amt) => update(n => n + amt),
        sub: (amt) => update(n => n - amt)
    };
}

export const res = playerRes({
    kelp: 0,
    sand: 0
});
```

I'm trying to edit the `add` and `sub` functions so that I can add, say, 5 kelp, or 10 sand at a time, without changing the rest of the object. However, it seems like with this setup, I'm only able to edit the entire object at once. I tried
`add: (type, amt) => update((n[type]) => (n[type]) + amt)`
but this threw a bunch of errors. I also tried to call something like `res['kelp'].add(5)` in my other files, but this didn't work either. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

The input will always be the entire object. You can modify individual properties of the store content but you also still have to return the entire object.

Something like:

```js
return {
    subscribe,
    add: (type, amt) => update(n => { n[type] += amt; return n }),
    sub: (type, amt) => update(n => { n[type] -= amt; return n })
};
```

```html
<button on:click={() => res.add('kelp', 1)}>+ kelp</button>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/4592ca433aa346cca09f9e270752c042?version=3.52.0)

Another approach, which does not rely on mutating objects, would be to create a copy with the target property replaced.

That would look like this:

```js
return {
    subscribe,
    add: (type, amt) => update(n => ({ ...n, [type]: n[type] + amt })),
    sub: (type, amt) => update(n => ({ ...n, [type]: n[type] - amt })),
};
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/08de37db135c4de3a9839073e7fe5d09?version=3.52.0)