# How can I declare, initialize and update a dictionary writable svelte/store variable?

Tags: javascript, typescript, data-structures, svelte, sveltekit

in the main app ./src/app.d.ts I declared the interface:

```
declare namespace App {
    interface Wallet {
        userAddress: string;
        network: string;
        balance: string;
        isConnected: boolean;
        contract: string;
        provider: string;
        contractOwner: string;
        amItheOwner: boolean;
    }
}
```

in the lib/utils/store.ts

```
/** 
* @params wallet methods: {set: ƒ, update: ƒ, subscribe: ƒ} 
*/
export let wallet: Wallet = {  
  userAddress  : "",
  network      : "",
  balance      : "",
  isConnected  : false,
  contract     : "",
  provider     : "",
  contractOwner: "",
  amItheOwner  : false
}

wallet = writable(
  wallet[userAddress].set(""),
  wallet[network].set(""),
  wallet[balance].set(""),
  wallet[isConnected].set(false),
  wallet[contract].set(""),
  wallet[provider].set(""),
  wallet[contractOwner].set(""),
  wallet[amItheOwner].set(false),
)
console.log('wallet[isConnected]: ', wallet[isConnected])
```

in the console.log() I got the error:

```
userAddress is not defined
ReferenceError: userAddress is not defined
```

pointing the line       `wallet[userAddress].set(""),` just after wallet = writable(

I tried several combination of syntax, initialization methods and so on so forth ... but :-( nothing ...

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using a store in a component property in the first place? In most cases that is not necessary because properties are reactive by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how accessing properties or updating stores works. You either use dot notation or you have to pass a string in brackets.

```js
wallet.userAddress
wallet['userAddress']
```

This only works for regular objects, for stores you first have to get the content/use something like `update` or in components simply via [`$` syntax](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-4-prefix-stores-with-$-to-access-their-values)

```js
$wallet.userAddress = ...
```

As for updating individual property values outside of components, see [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74297464/svelte-custom-stores-with-objects-how-do-i-only-update-one-key-at-a-time).

Creating a store does *not* add a `set` method for each property.

---

The types are also wrong, stores have generic types, depending on whether they can be read or also written. If you create a writable, the type would be:

```js
export let wallet: Writable<Wallet>;
```

Which can only be assigned a `writable` instance.

It can be initialized just by wrapping the object:

```js
export let wallet: Writable<Wallet> = writable({
  userAddress  : "",
  network      : "",
  balance      : "",
  isConnected  : false,
  contract     : "",
  provider     : "",
  contractOwner: "",
  amItheOwner  : false
});
```